# Continuity of quantiles as function of measure.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, quantile

Let $P(R)$ be the probability measures on the real numbers $R$ and fix $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Define

$$Q_{\alpha} : P(R) \to R $$

as the function taking a measure $\mu \in P(R)$ to its $\alpha$-th quantile, defined by

$$Q_{\alpha}(\mu):=\inf \{x\in R: \alpha \leq \mu ((-\infty, x ] ) \}.$$

**I am intereseted in any results concerning the continuity of the function $Q_{\alpha}$.**

I am open as to the distance put on the space $P(R)$ and possibly restricting to probability measures with moments etc.

Comment: I don't totally understand what you have written, but your $Q_{\alpha}$ looks like the inverse of the cumulative distribution function and so will be well defined (and continuous and strictly increasing) if the cumulative distribution function is continuous and strictly increasing.

Comment: Yes,  $\alpha \mapsto Q_{\alpha}$ is continuous at all continuity points of the CDF of $\mu$ but I am interested in continuity w.r.t. the measure.

Comment: If you are completely open, then $Q_\alpha$ is continuous in discrete metric on measures. If you are not, you are essentially asking to check whether $Q_\alpha$ is continuous in at least one topology on measures, and there quite some of them.